# xquery order by two variables not working

Tags: xml, sql-order-by, xquery

In Xquery, I want to sort the xml example like below:

```
<library>
    <book>
         <author>abc</author>
         <author>def</author>
         <author>bcd</author>
    </book>
    <article>
         <author>utc</author>
         <author>abg</author>
    </article>
    <ebook>
         <author>zerg</author>
    </ebook>
</library>
```

and I am trying to get the output to be..

```
<library>
    <article>
         <author>abg</author>
         <author>utc</author>
    </article>
    <book>
         <author>abc</author>
         <author>bcd</author>
         <author>def</author>
    </book>
    <ebook>
         <author>zerg</author>
    </ebook>
</library>
```

In my query, I had tried something like :

```
for $s in //library
order by $s ascending, $s//* ascending
return $s
```

but it seems like not accepting two condition in "order by".

Before I ask this question, I found the similar post in here but it is not related to the solution that I'm looking for. Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

### Problem 1: Sorting libraries vs sorting library contents

The first problem is you're only sorting the `<library/>` container element. Loop over all its children instead: `/library/*`.

### Problem 2: Sorting on different levels

Furthermore, the `order by` you're using only orders on the "library item" level, thus you're ordering for articles, books, ebooks, and if there are multiple of any then ordering those items by the author names. This is neither want you want to achieve nor working, as you cannot order after a sequence of items (there is no order defined on sequences of items in XQuery).

To demonstrate what's going on, lets both slightly modify the input and limit to the *first* author:

```
let $xml := document {
  <library>
    <book>
         <author>abc</author>
         <author>def</author>
         <author>bcd</author>
    </book>
    <article>
         <author>utc</author>
         <author>abg</author>
    </article>
    <article>
         <author>foobar</author>
    </article>
    <ebook>
         <author>zerg</author>
    </ebook>
  </library>
}

for $s in $xml//library/*
order by $s/name() ascending, ($s//*)[1] ascending
return $s
```

This will list all articles as expected, and sort the articles based on the first author's name:

```
<article>
  <author>foobar</author>
</article>
<article>
  <author>utc</author>
  <author>abg</author>
</article>
<book>
  <author>abc</author>
  <author>def</author>
  <author>bcd</author>
</book>
<ebook>
  <author>zerg</author>
</ebook>
```

### And a solution

The solution is to construct new result elements, so you can also order the authors for each item:

```
element library {
  for $item in /library/*
  let $name := local-name($item)
  order by $item
  return element { $name } {
    for $author in $item/author
    order by $author
    return $author
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hate to answer a request for a solution in language A by suggesting a solution in language B, but what you are doing here falls into the class of problems which XSLT handles much better than XQuery.

In XSLT it can be done with a single template rule, which is completely generic and makes no assumptions about the actual content of your XML:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*">
      <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
      <xsl:sort select="."/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a nested query to do this:

```
<library>{
  for $item in /library/*
    order by name($item)
  return 
   element {node-name($item)} {
     for $author in $item/author
       order by $author
     return $author
   }
}</library>
```